# Property 'navigateByData' does not exist on type 'Router' Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jasmine

Estoy realizando test unitarios, en Angular con Jasmine y Karma, pero estoy teniendo el siguiente error a la hora de testear mi componente:

```
TypeError: this.router.getNavigatedData is not a function
```

El constructor de mi componente es el siguiente:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ){}
```

Mi test es el siguiente:

```
describe('EjemploComponent', ()=>{

    let component:EjemploComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<EjemploComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ 
                EjemploComponent
            ],
            providers:[
                HttpClient,
                HttpHandler,
                UtilService
            ],
            imports: [ 
                RouterTestingModule,
                SharedModule,
                ComponentesGeneralesModule,
                EncabezadoModule
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();  
    }));

    beforeEach(()=>{

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EjemploComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        
    })


    it('Debaria crear el componente',()=>{
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

El error indica que no existe el metodo getNavigatedData, pero mi componente lo utiliza sin problemas. Intente agregar un spy pero no sirvió y ya no se que mas intentar.

**EDICION:**

El modulo Router es el siguiente:

```
import { NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router/src/router";
export declare const REFLECT_CLASS: any;
declare module "@angular/router" {
    class Router extends REFLECT_CLASS.ROUTER {
        private _sendingData;
        navigateByData(data: ReflectRouter.NavigatedData): Promise<boolean>;
        getNavigatedData(): any;
    }
}
export declare namespace ReflectRouter {
    interface NavigatedData {
        url: Array<any>;
        data: any;
        extras?: NavigationExtras;
    }
    function init(): void;
}
```

Comment: Es que literal en la [Documentacion de router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) no existe ese metodo.

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
const params:Params = {
        'documento':35643161,
        'cuenta':596556,
    } 

const fakeActivatedRoute = {
        snapshot: { 
             params
        }
} as ActivatedRoute;

beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ 
                EjemploComponent
            ],
            providers:[
                UtilService,
                {
                    provide: Router ,
                    useClass: RouterMock
                },
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute, 
                    useValue: fakeActivatedRoute
                },
                Location,
                {
                    provide: LocationStrategy ,
                    useClass: PathLocationStrategy
                },
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}
            ],
            imports: [ 
                SharedModule,
                ComponentesGeneralesModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                EncabezadoModule
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();  
        
    }));
```

Elimine el `RouterTestingModule` y añadí a los providers `Router` realizo un mock con la clase `RouterMock`, al realizar este cambio me pedia la declaracion en providers de `ActivatedRoute` y mockie para que me devuelva los parametros 'documento' y 'cuenta'.
Luego me pidio la declaracion de Location en providers, al declararlo me generaba un nuevo error que lo solucione añadiendo lo siguiente en providers:

```
{
     provide: LocationStrategy ,
     useClass: PathLocationStrategy
},
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}
```

En mi caso particular, tenia un nuevo error producido por las clases `HttpClient` y `HttpHandler` que lo solucione eliminando estas clases de providers y añadiendo a imports el modulo `HttpClientTestingModule`